# Xcode Target dependencies error after switching SDKs

Tags: xcode, target

I have been working on my project with xcode 5 for the past few days. I've switched over to Xcode 4 because I wanted to make sure everything in my project would be compatible with IOS 6.

After reverting the XIBs, I get the following error when I attempt to run my project.
Every other time I run, my app crashes, but every other time it does not... Weird.

```
target specifies product type 'com.apple.product-type.bundle.unit-test', but there's no such product type for the 'iphonesimulator' platform
```

How can I go about solving this issue?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I couldn't solve it. To continue working I kept using xcode 5, but switched my XIB viewing target to IOS 6 and under, and installed the IOS 6 simulator onto xcode 5.

Comment: I'm having the same message when using Travis-CI for a small project. Did you solve this?

Comment: I would update to xcode 5 and install all of their IOS 7 changes. I was experiencing this issue during Apple's xcode 5 beta release.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Xcode4.6 run my app show the Error!
but!
I click xode product ---> clean  !
solve the error!